# Deleting Specific Rows from Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

I have a very large dataframe that I am trying to clean up. Here is a sample of the dataframe.

```
[in]: dftrain

[out]:
    date    store_nbr   item_nbr    units       tavg    preciptotal
2012-01-01       1          1          0         42         0.05
2012-01-01       1          2          2         42         0.05
2012-01-01       1          3          0         42         0.05 
2012-01-01       1          4          0         42         0.05 

2012-01-01       2          1          0         62         0.15
2012-01-01       2          2          0         62         0.15
2012-01-01       2          3          20        62         0.15
2012-01-01       2          4          1         62         0.15

2012-01-01       3          1          0         72         1.05
2012-01-01       3          2          0         72         1.05
2012-01-01       3          3          29        72         1.05
2012-01-01       3          3          0         72         1.05
...(New Day) 
  date      store_nbr   item_nbr     units      tavg    preciptotal
2012-01-02       1          1          0         47         0.10
2012-01-02       1          2          0         47         0.10
2012-01-02       1          3          0         47         0.10 
2012-01-02       1          4          0         47         0.10 

2012-01-02       2          1          0         60         0.0
2012-01-02       2          2          0         60         0.0
2012-01-02       2          3          5         60         0.0
2012-01-02       2          4          0         60         0.0

2012-01-02       3          1          0         67         .23
2012-01-02       3          2          0         67         .23
2012-01-02       3          3          2         67         .23
2012-01-02       3          3          0         67         .23
...
```

I have a dictionary with the str_nbr as the key and item_nbr as the values of the store and item numbers I want to keep. Here is a sample dictionary: `{'1': [2], '2': [3,4], '3': [3]}`
What I want to do is go store by store and delete all the rows with the item_nbr NOT contained as the values of my dictionary. So in this example when I have dropped the undesired rows I would have this...

```
 [in]: dfrain_drop

[out]:
    date    store_nbr   item_nbr    units       tavg    preciptotal

2012-01-01       1          2          2         42         0.05

2012-01-01       2          3          20        62         0.15
2012-01-01       2          4          1         62         0.15

2012-01-01       3          3          29        72         1.05

...(New Day) 
  date      store_nbr   item_nbr     units      tavg    preciptotal

2012-01-02       1          2          0         47         0.10

2012-01-02       2          3          5         60         0.0
2012-01-02       2          4          0         60         0.0

2012-01-02       3          3          0         67         .23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the fastest solution I could come up with:

```
is_good = lambda group: group.isin(keep[group.name])
result = df[df.groupby('store_nbr')['item_nbr'].apply(is_good)]
```

It splits up the DataFrame by store_nbr, calls is_good on each each group (apply) to determine the rows you want to keep, puts everything back together in the right order, and then takes a subset of rows from the original frame.

Answer (score 0):

Using the first day of your sample dataset:

```
keep = {'1': [2], '2': [3,4], '3': [3]}

parts = []
for i in keep: parts.append(dftrain.query(
               "item_nbr in %s and store_nbr == %d"%(keep[i],int(i))
               ))
pd.concat(parts)
```

> ```
>           date  store_nbr  item_nbr  units  tavg  preciptotal
> 1   2012-01-01          1         2      2    42         0.05
> 10  2012-01-01          3         3     29    72         1.05
> 11  2012-01-01          3         3      0    72         1.05
> 6   2012-01-01          2         3     20    62         0.15
> 7   2012-01-01          2         4      1    62         0.15
> ```

result, all one tidied-up dataset. ( I believe your sample output is missing an item from store 3.)

Comment: Well that's actually not what I want. I want to keep the values that are not in my dictionary.

Comment: Your OP says " delete all the rows with the item_nbr NOT contained as the values of my dictionary". "Delete if not contained" is "keep if contained"; this also matches your sample result. Anyway, you can flip which you keep by using `not in` instead of `in` in the `query`.

Comment: I see you edited the post, but it's still not consistent with your comment above (and store 3 kept only one of the item_nbr 3 rows).

Comment: Ok yes you are right, I do want to keep the values in the dictionary. I would like to avoid using an append because my dataframe is has over four million lines, so I think an append might take a little too long. I am going to work on it more over the weekend.

Comment: Okay, but if this answers your question, at least mark it so.

Comment: Well yes, it answers my question in this limited example, but not in a more general sense. Also your output doesn't include the second day, and has an extra row for the first day in store 3.

Comment: Your sample output is wrong re: the cases for store 3. There are two item_nbr==3 cases in the input for both day 1 and day 2, both should survive. Also, this code will work on a dftrain file of any size if formatted this way. I've tested it on your complete sample data.